# Install nlog into visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, nuget, nlog

I'm writing code in the `C#` WinForms desktop application. I have an issue in some places of my form then I don't know which place does work which is not working at that time nlog can help us to trace the process of application. But I can't configure it in my `visual studio 2012` from `nuget`. Nuget itself dosn't work asking always updating it  like this
[image]

please give me advices how to install `nlog` into visual studio 2012 . If yes withou using nuget

Comment: If you are having issues with NuGet then address those. You should install your library dependencies using Nuget including `nLog`. Start by googling the *English* error message(s) you have from NuGet and see where that takes you. I can't offer any more advice because I don't even recognize the language in the screenshot, sorry. Do keep in mind that [so] is English only but there is a [es.so] and [ru.so] site as well.

Comment: how I can install nLog withou using nuget?

Comment: thank you for you effort. I appreciate it

Comment: Download  nlog library from https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/ , unzip the file  , add reference to nlog

Answer (score 1):

Download the  [NUPKG file](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/NLog) by clicking the download link.

It's a zip file. You can unzip the package in a folder and reference nlog.dll to your project.

Configure nlog using xml file or by code   by reading the [help](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial)

Nuget tool do these tasks automatically.